# Newton ' s second law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

> A boy is sliding down from a third floor window of a building. As he slides down the rope faster and faster, he becomes frightened.
>   Then, he grabs harder on rope, increasing the tension on the rope. As soon as the upward tension in the rope becomes equal to his weight,
>
> Will the boy stop OR will the boy continues down at a constant velocity?

I am convinced that the answer is the 2nd one beacause when a= 0 , the tension force will be equal to weight. Thus when a=0 , velocity will be constant. 
But the first answ seemed correct as well , because the force will cancel out each other. 
So how ? Help me

Answer (score 1):

Considering Friction less slide and No Air Resistance

When the tension in the string becomes equal to his weight the boy will stop because if T = mg and the downward force is mgsinϴ and ϴ must be < 90° (slide).

So, According to Second Law, If there is some force there must be some acceleration (in this case retardation).

The Boy will stop sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Every object has inertia, meaning that it wants to continue on the path it is currently on and with the same velocity. That's why, according to the second law, a net force is required to produce acceleration and NOT movement. If an object is travelling at velocity $v$ it will continue to travel at velocity $v$ forever unless a resultant force acts on it.

Therefore, in the example you gave, when the forces balance out the boy just falls at a constant speed, because without a resultant force there is no deceleration slowing him down, and that's because his inertia means he wants to continue moving with a constant velocity.